# Is it okay to connect raw ruby sockets to event machine UNIX server?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have a UNIX server started and the code goes like:

```
module UNIX_Server
  def receive_data(data)
    send_data "testing"
  end

  def unbind
    puts "[server] client disconnected."
  end
 end

 EM::run {
  EM::start_unix_domain_server('/tmp/file.sock', UNIX_Server)
 }
```

This works fine, and I am trying to connect to this using a Ruby 1.8.7
 UNIX Socket:

```
 s = UNIXSocket.new
 s.puts "test"
 s.gets
```

The problem here is that my gets method seems to hang and the client
 only gets data when I do a Ctrl-C and terminate the server. What am I
 missing here?

Answer (score 3):

[`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-gets) reads a whole line at a time. Your client is waiting for the newline char which your server never sends.

Using

```
send_data "testing\n" # note the newline character
```

in your server should work, or you could use [`IO#getc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-getc) in a loop.